# Python Pandas DataFrame - Creating Change Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with this column name

```
timestamp,stockname,total volume traded
```

There are multiple stock names at each time frame

```
11:00,A,100
11:00,B,500
11:01,A,150
11:01,B,600
11:02,A,200
11:02,B,650
```

I want to create a ChangeInVol column such that each stock carries its own difference like

```
timestamp, stock,total volume, change in volume
11:00,A,100,NaN
11:00,B,500,NAN
11:01,A,150,50
11:01,B,600,100
11:02,A,200,50
11:03,B,650,50
```

If it were a single stock, I could have done

```
df['ChangeVol'] = df['TotalVol'] - df['TotalVol'].shift(1)
```

but there are multiple stocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
#if columns not sorted
df = df.sort_values(['timestamp','stockname'])

df['change in volume'] = df.groupby('stockname')['total volume traded'].diff()
print (df)
  timestamp stockname  total volume traded  change in volume
0     11:00         A                  100               NaN
1     11:00         B                  500               NaN
2     11:01         A                  150              50.0
3     11:01         B                  600             100.0
4     11:02         A                  200              50.0
5     11:02         B                  650              50.0
```

Comment: It is a time series data, so is sorting still required on timestamp ? or we can just do away with sort on stock name

Comment: I think if `timestamp` is sorted, then `df = df.sort_values(['timestamp','stockname'])` should be omit.

Comment: Why can't you just sort on stock name (omitting timestamp in sort order) and apply  what is suggested originally? I believe @Tahseen has commented  the same thing above.

Comment: @SameerMahajan - output will be different, try it.

Comment: @jezrael timestamp is index. How can we sort on index after group by and then performance diff() operation ? Instead of 'timestamp' would we use df.index as a replacement ?

Comment: `df = df.sort_index()` I think.

Comment: df['ChangeInVolume'] = df.groupby('symbol')['totalTradedVolume'].diff() failed saying ValueError

Comment: Can you explain more? Maybe if add some data for better output help me understand problem. Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael I have emailed you sample data and the Jupyter Notebook code

Comment: Good idea, I check it.